# build a formatted string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I need to build a string from some columns into another column, the trailing zeros must be removed from month and day :

YEAR=2008;**MONTH=1;DAY=1**;ID=1021; ... etc

For the day piece I've used the TO_CHAR(D_RIC,'D') function to remove leading zeros. Is there a format option for months to remove starting zeros too ?

Comment: That's "leading zeros" not "trailing zeros". You only talk about "trailing zeros" for digits following a decimal point. Don't have the reputation to edit, so my inner Grammar Nazi has to add a comment.

Comment: i apologize for my bad english and thanks both for fixing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Fill Mode"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) (FM):

```
select to_char (datecol, 'FMMM') from mytable;
```